# how to retrieve a single value from sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if a condition is true or not by retrieving a single integer value from database using sql query in PHP.. Here is the code -

```
$stmt = $dbo->prepare("SELECT Qty FROM sample.stock WHERE stock_ID=$s_stock_ID AND component='$component' LIMIT 1");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['Qty']))) 
{ 
   $Q = $_GET['Qty'];
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
   {
    print_r($row);
   } 
}

if($Qty <= $Q) // comparison of integers
    { 
     echo "success";
    }
else
{
 echo "failed";
}
```

I cant understand where am i stuck here.. It would be great if anyone can point out my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an error or what?

Comment: use `$row->Qty` where Qty is your column name if you fetch as array use $row['Qty']. Hope helps

Comment: @MattiasLindberg i dont know about errors because i am scripting on simple notepad.. output is "failed"

Comment: It's not `$Qty` it is `$row->Qty` and that too, inside the loop.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky $Qty is declared globally with some integer value in it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your code to add Try/Catch blocks. You also need to move Qty into the while loop. You can fetch it as an object or as an array. In the example below I'm fetching it as an object.

```
    $Q = $_GET['Qty'];
    $sql = "SELECT Qty FROM sample.stock WHERE stock_ID=$s_stock_ID AND component='$component' LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $dbo->prepare( $sql );

    try {
        $stmt->execute( array($_GET['Qty']) );
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) 
        {
            if( $row->Qty <= $Q ) { 
                echo "success";
            } else {
                echo "failed";
            }
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: If no output check print_r($row) what data is outputing, and paste it here please

Comment: array(2) { ["Qty"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(2) { ["Qty"]=> string(3) "160" [0]=> string(3) "160" } array(2) { ["Qty"]=> string(3) "122" [0]=> string(3) "122" } array(2) { ["Qty"]=> string(3) "208" [0]=> string(3) "208" } array(2) { ["Qty"]=> string(3) "302" [0]=> string(3) "302" } array(2) { ["Qty"]=> string(3) "111" [0]=> string(3) "111" } array(2) { ["Qty"]=> string(3) "334" [0]=> string(3) "334" } array(2) { ["Qty"]=> string(3) "333" [0]=> string(3) "333" } array(2) { ["Qty"]=> string(3) "553" [0]=> string(3) "553" } array(2) { ["Qty"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: change `$row->Qty` to `$row['Qty']` in your code, it doesn't look like you set this `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` otherwise the code would have worked.

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer by clicking on the checkbox (the thing under the down vote)